# How to allow a role to add users without giving them a password?

Tags: entities, users

I have a situation where I would like a specific user role be able to add users without assigning them a password but I can't seem to find a way to do this. Has anyone done this before? I feel like this is something commonly done. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the module I have and currently, this code just outputs at the top of the screen for all pages? This is my first module.

Here is my hide_some_fields.module file

```
function hide_some_fields_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) 
{

  global $user;

  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') 
  {                    
    if(in_array('operator', array_values($user->roles))) 
    { 
      unset($form['account']['pass']);  

    }
  }
}
```

Here is my .info file as well:

```
name = Hide Some Fields
description = Hides some fields. The password field when the operator adds patients. 
core = 7.x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;

  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    if (in_array('your_role', array_values($user->roles))) {
      unset($form['account']['pass']);
    }
  }
}
```

This should work for you - just remember to change modulename to your module.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Would this go in a custom module?

Comment: Yeah, throw it in a custom module. If you have any problems just let me know.

Comment: Did you think about the password field that's required when people want to log in? This seems like a bad idea, give them a default password in order to allow them to log in to the site.

Comment: Users without a password cannot log-in - you could hook on to user_save to provide a default password as JurgenR is suggesting.

Comment: I want to mimick that its like when a user registers and requires admin approval

Comment: When I add my module, the code is just output as plain text at the top. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Seems like there's no <?php tag?

Comment: lol, that was it

Comment: This works but, after I submit the user, I get: Notice: Undefined index: pass in user_register_submit() (line 3748 of /home/mghen/public_html/mobile_mashavu/modules/user/user.module).

Comment: Can I get rid of this some how?

Comment: I fixed this by changing line 3748 to check isset(...['pass']) and if it's not, I assign it a default value.

Comment: Changing line 3478 of a core module? Very abd idea, this breaks on the next update.

Answer (score 2):

People need a password in order to log in to the site. 
Therefore you need to allways insert a password when creating new users.
You can add a default password and set the field as hidden on a specific role but new users will need to know the default password in order to log in.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {

    $default_value = isset($form_state['build_info']['args'][0]['pass'] ? $form_state['build_info']['args'][0]['pass'] : 'DEFAULT PASSWORD';

    if (in_array('YOUR ROLE', array_values($user->roles))) {
      $form['account']['pass']['#default_value'] = $default_value;
      $form['account']['pass']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Ok I took the time to work this out and therefor I want to adjust my solution:
In order to get this properly working you need to override the full $form['account']['pass'] array. This is because it has the password_confirm type as default, which has the extra confirm field, keeping this type will result in an empty password field on the node submit.
Clive is absolutely right, using a #default_value on a password field results in an error so we need to use the #value. Thas was the unsupported operand types error.
Also, in my first answer I added a condition so see if the form is used to edit a user but now I know that the registration form and edit form are two different forms calling the same user_account_form so we can remove the condition.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    if (in_array('USER ROLE', array_values($user->roles))) {
      $form['account']['pass'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password',
        '#size' => 25,
        '#access' => FALSE,
        '#value' => 'DEFAULT PASSWORD',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I tested this code and it works like a charm so if you have any problems with it feel free to contact me.

Comment: looks good, trying this now.

Comment: This does not work: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/mghen/public_html/mobile_mashavu/includes/form.inc on line 2326 ... Can we assign it a default value since it is a password field?

Comment: Password elements can't have a `#default_value` (see the [FAPI reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7)), try using `#value` instead

Comment: Due to comments of Mike and @Clive I edited my answer.