# How to allow a role to add user without adding user name, password, roles, etc

Tags: users

I created a role. I would like the users of the role be able to add some people without entering user name, password, roles, active, etc. These people that the role will add are actually customers. When we get new customers, specific role users will login to the system and add the customers to the system and these people/customers do not need to access the system.

I did search google and i found this site [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31559/how-to-allow-a-role-to-add-users-without-giving-them-a-password) but I could not follow it.

Do you know how I can do it?

---

I thought about it. Here is the problem. After I add the customers, I need to be able to link each customer to another module content(e.e. xxx.com/module/add). The module that I am using it has a field which allows to select a user only exists in the system. If I create a content type 'customer' like you said, module field does not see these customers when i go to xxx.com/module/add. Module field only sees these customers if they are users of the system. Not sure how to proceed?

---

Other module name is simple reservation which has a field 'This reservation is for'. This field is only takes users names from the system.

sr_week.tpl.php has the below code to get the users ( i guess)

```
<div id="srFor">
          <?php if (($reservation["for_uid"] > 0) && ($reservation["uid"] != $reservation["for_uid"])) {
              print(" (". t("for") ." ". l($for->name, 'user/'. $for->uid)) . ")";}
              else print("&nbsp;");?>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is this other module that you are using? There might be a suitable replacement that would allow you to use nodes.

Comment: I added comment above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like these people you're adding should not be added as users to the system.  You should only add users if they are going to be actually logging into Drupal.

If you're just trying to keep a record of clients then you should store them as nodes.  Configure a new content type called something like "customer" and add and configure the appropriate fields that you wish to store about these customers.

Comment: I have added comment above.